# in npm Windows version, global installation seems not working

Tags: npm, global, node-modules

Using npm 3.10.10 on Windows, global installation is not storing modules under "<\user>\AppData\Roaming\npm". It is actually installing under **<\working directory>**\.node_modules_global.

By command "npm config ls -l --global", it shows "prefix" is overridden by user configuration in .npmrc. Then, I find in <\node installation dir>\node_modules\npm\npmrc" file:

```
prefix=${APPDATA}\npm
```

Is it a bug? Shouldn't global modules be installed somewhere available to the entire machine? Otherwise, .node_modules_global folders could be created everywhere on the machine now and "global" doesn't work as "global".

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by my own. There is an unexpected user config file under C:\User\.npmrc, which sets up a customized "prefix=.node_modules_global". That setting overrides builtin config <\node installation dir>\node_modules\npm\npmrc.